# How can i get two windows(frames) that can interact with eachother? Actionscript 3, Starling

Tags: actionscript-3, window, multiple-instances, starling-framework

I'll try to explain my question as much as possible but feel free to ask any question if something is unclear.

I have my main program which handles everything, but I want a second window to show stuff like output and messages. This second screen will be underneath the first one and will only display  text.

A example would be a game like hangman. Where my first window would should the letters and figure and the second screen would show messages like "That letter wasn't right. 3 Tries left." or something similar.

I know you can use

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("external.swf"), "_blank");
```

To get a second swf to load. But that isn't really what I'm looking for.

So long story short:

I need a two windows for 1 program. Is this possible or should I make two programs that somehow interact with one another.

Any information or links to helpful site would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using adobe Air you can create more windows:

```
var options:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions(); 
options.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.STANDARD; 
options.type = NativeWindowType.UTILITY 
options.transparent = false; 
options.resizable = false; 
options.maximizable = false; 
var newWindow:NativeWindow = new NativeWindow(options);
newWindow.activate();
```

This does mean you can't use this on the web though.

Edit: Take a look at [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e0a.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be using [Adobe Air Workers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html). You layout your views as you wish, but the communication will be threw the workers API. The biggest benefits of workers is that they are using different threads of GPU and dramatically improve your performance.